# Python Websocket Not opening. Instantly saying 'Connection Closed'

Tags: python, websocket, stream, binance

I am having a bit of an error in which I am trying to stream live Ethereum prices using the binance API. But when I run the code it immidietly just outputs 'Closed Connection' without anything else. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
import websocket 

def on_open(ws):
    print('Opened Connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('Closed Connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('Recieved Message')

SOCKET = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1s'

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Thank you in advance,

I have tried the documentation and rerunning it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `WebSocketApp` constructor's `on_close` and `on_error` param functions can have additional params to receive error messages: `on_error(ws, error)`, `on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg)`. You need to find out what happened in your environment. We cannot reproduce `connection closed` with the codes above.